# Getting inner html using regexp including inner tags

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

I need to extract inner content of some div including all inner tags (could be the same as outer. E.g.

```
<div id="test1">Test1<div id="test2">Test2<div id="test3">Test3</div></div></div>
```

Should gives:

```
Test1<div id="test2">Test2<div id="test3">Test3</div></div>
```

Tried a lot of approaches but nothing works good.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there a reason you are not using html parsing instead of regex?

Comment: Yep. There are. It's not browser but server (PHP) code.